# How to get the top 3 most liked comments on a Facebook fanpage?

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How can I get the top 3 most liked comments on a Facebook fanpage? Here is what I am trying to do:

- Search all comments on page `x`.
- Select `[1,2,3]` from `x` where `[1,2,3]` are the most liked comments in descending order.
- Output `[1,2,3]` to HTML.
- Output my comment to HTML.

Comment: lol. Thanks, yoda. And now I have -3 next my post, which I can only assume must be a BAD thing.

Comment: What you did should work, could you give more details (output etc.)?

Comment: This is only pseudocode! What I am trying to do is use FQL or or the FB-opengraph to get the number of likes from a post output in JSON. Here fore example is a page containing JSON from Fb's platform, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=platform However I have been unable to extract each and every post and then determining the number of likes of each. Thanks for trying to help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Fb is bloked at my work I could not test:

```
SELECT comments
FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN
(
    ###HERE A QUERY FOR A Fb_id (fanpage/link/video/message/status ...) ###
)
ORDER BY like DESC
LIMIT 0,3;
```